# Rollback and change or create a new migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I am just curious,
Suppose I create this migration:

```
def change
  create_table :pages do |t|
    t.string :title
    t.text :content

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

and then I run the migration.

Now after a couple of hours I remember that I should have added a `slug` column too.

Now (supposing I haven't created any other migrations after this one), should I rollback and add the new field here (in this migration), or should I create a new migration and add the filed there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't pushed it out to production, I'd say just roll back and add it into the existing migration.  If you have deployed it to production, then I'd make another migration.

This is, however, mostly a matter of preference, if there's no data that will be lost as a result.  I just like to get into the habit of doing things the safer way in production.

Comment: Yes, I am still on development.

Comment: Then I'd say just use rake db:rollback and then make the change and migrate again.